# Download Figure from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I used graphviz to visualize my decision tree in Jupyter Notebook. Now my question is how to show full decision tree figure in Jupyter Notebook? Or how to save the picture of the decision tree from Jupyter Notebook?

Now I'm only able to view the entire tree by scroll down. I want to see the entire tree in one window.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This gives a PDF:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

g = Digraph('G', filename='hello.gv')
g.edge('Hello', 'World')
g.view()
```

When using Jupyter you can do:
`--> file --> export notebook as --> export notebook to markdown`. You'll get a zip file where a png is included.